# How would the following REST service be described in WSDL?

Tags: xml, rest, wsdl

```
POST http://site.com/customer

<customer>
  <firstName>Paul</firstName>
  <lastName>Serby</lastName>
  <email>paul@site.com</email>
</customer>
```

---- Success: HTTP Response 200

```
<response>
</response>
```

---- Failure: HTTP Response 400

```
<response>
  <errors>
    <error>Missing email</error>
  </errors>
</response>
```

Comment: WSDL is typically for SOAP, not for REST. Do you mean [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)?

Comment: That's what I thought, but this article seems to suggest it is possible. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/

Comment: Yes, the WSDL 2.0 spec competes with WADL. Personally, I think any sort of descriptor language for a RESTful web service is missing the point...

Comment: In most cases, the "description" for a REST interface is the human-language documentation, in other words exactly what you've already provided in your question.  I don't know of any tools (are there any?) that generate code for a REST client, from a WSDL document. So even if you succeed in your original goal, there is limited utility.

Comment: Salesforce allows you to pass in a WSDL for a SOAP or REST service and it creates adaptor classes for you.